# Failed to assume role after logging in SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-cli

The UI path works for me. So let me walk you through this first.

1. log in with SSO URL
2. Choose the account from SSO and AWS Console opens
3. Assume another role
4. Open s3 and it works

Now I tried to do the same thing with CLI

1. log in with SSO
2. Copy access_key, secret_key, session_token from SSO page
3. Run export for access_key, secret_key, session_token in CLI
4. Run `aws s3 ls` to test but didn't work (no problem)
5. Run aws sts assume-role but didn't work

   ```
   $ aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/SomeRole" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session --region ap-southeast-2
   ```

> => An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_some_role_assume_all_123abc/myid@some.domain is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/SomeRole

Comment: have you tried opening up a fresh terminal session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. For the second part in my question, step 1 and 2 are wrong.

First you need to run

```
aws configure sso
```

This will run some magic and set up a profile under ~/.aws/config

Then you need to run `aws sts assume-role` with the flag --profile and the value is the newly created profile.

Then it will work.